# Understanding the many function parameters in .reduce()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reduce, arrow-functions

The `.reduce()` method below, taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38839205/1417223) contains many parameters (appearantly called *destructuring objects*).

What functionality do these parameters represent?

```
let {result} = array.reduce(({arg_1, arg_2, arg_3}, arg_4)=> {
}, {result: [], arg_2: 0, arg_3: undefined})
return result
```

Comment: really? - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: I believe what you're confused about here is *argument unpacking*.

Comment: We can't tell what those arguments represent: they're just generic variable names. Are you trying to ask about the syntax of using `{}` like that?

Comment: @deceze exactly, thank you for describing it better than I did in the question.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes, that's exactly what I got confused about. Explanation on `.reduce()` with two simple arguments are everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Syntax) takes 2 parameters,

1. callback
2. initialValue

[Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Description)'s callback gets 4 parameters:

1. previousValue
2. currentValue
3. currentIndex
4. array

Value of `previousValue` is `initialValue` at the start of loop. If no value is passed, *first element* is taken as `previousValue` and `currentValue` will have *next value*. From them, `previousValue` will hold the value returned in previous iteration.

#### Sample

#### No initial value

```js
var a = [1,2,4,4,5,6,7,8];

a.reduce(function(p,c,i,a){
  console.log(p,c,i,a);
  return c
})
```

#### With initial value

```js
var a = [1,2,4,4,5,6,7,8];

a.reduce(function(p,c,i,a){
  console.log(p,c,i,a);
  return c
},0)
```

#### Reference

[Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 2):

In case OP stumbles over the destructuring notation, for the given example, the first parameter is the initial value (described with the [provided links](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) of the first two comments), working as a collector or accumulator object. It is made up of the first three arguments of another method. The result is written by a destructuring assignment, thus, there will be 3 variables, `arg_1`, `arg_2` and `arg_3` derived from the equally named arguments of the finally returned collector object.

> edit, for the OP's provided example code has changed ...

The next example takes the OP's linked SO code reference into account ...

```
let {slots} = array.reduce(({slots, count, prev}, item)=> {

    // ... do something with slots
    // ...
    // while iterating always needs to return
    // an equally structured collector object

    return {slots, count: count + 1, prev: item}

}, {slots: [], count: 0, prev: undefined})

/*
return slots; // does not really make sense within this shortened example's context.
*/
```

... is equal to ...

```
var slots = array.reduce(function (collector, item) {

    var
        slots = collector.slots,
        count = collector.count,
        prev  = collector.prev;

    // ... do something with slots
    // ...
    // while iterating always needs to return
    // an equally structured collector object

    return {slots: slots, count: count + 1, prev: item};

}, {slots: [], count: 0, prev: undefined}).slots;
```

Answer (score 2):

The [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method accepts two arguments.

Syntax:

> arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])

So, in your example the callback is used as first argument is [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Let's break it:

```
1. ({arg_1, arg_2, arg_3}, arg_4)=> {}  //the callback
2. {arg_1: [], arg_2: 0, arg_3: undefined} // the initial value
```

And `({arg_1, arg_2, arg_3}, arg_4)` has **two** arguments for [arrow function](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html), first is declared as object.

You can notice that the initial value for `arg_4` is missing.