# How should functions be written within a React class?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to adapt code from [a SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38839205/1417223), with functions and variables written as below:

```
const getIntervals = n=> availability=> {
}

let availability = [
]
```

Are those normally fine to use in a react class (see below) or do they need to be rewritten?

```
class Calendar extends React.Component {}
```

The reason for asking is that I use a React implementation [for Rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) and do get an error including that function and variable naming pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `class` and extending `Component`, you can use simple methods for most things:

```
class Calendar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.date = props.date;
  }

  render() {
    return <span>{this.date.toString()}</span>;
  }
}

Calendar.propTypes = {
  date: React.PropTypes.date.isRequired
};
```

You cannot use methods for `propTypes` or anything that would be an initial field if you were using an object literal. Those need to be attached after the class has been declared (`propTypes`) or in the constructor (initial `state`).

Comment: So how should the code provided in the question be converted to work?

Comment: @FellowStranger use methods, unless it was a property (not a method) of the equivalent object literal component.

Comment: An alternative would be a [stateless functional component](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components).

Comment: I am react noob. Just interested to know from you @ssube that, why `propTypes` you didn't define inside the class?

Comment: @ArupRakshit `class` does not support an equivalent of `createComponent({propTypes: {...}})` in the class declaration or constructor, so you need to use `Foo.propTypes` after declaring the class. React has [an example here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes).

Comment: Just a tip if you are going to create methods with the `extend` syntax, if you want access to `this` from within the method then you'd need to bind it in the class constructor, eg: `constructor(props) { super(props); this.myMethod = this.myMethod.bind(this); }`

Comment: @inostia as with es5 classes, you need to bind event handlers, but `{this.foo()}` will still work as expected (because you are explicitly calling `foo` on `this`).

Answer (score 4):

**Pure Functions**, which dont modify the passed value, are always fine to use anywhere.

Its also fine to use them in a React Class directly, but common functions like string modifications, array sorting algorithms, which you are using a lot across your app and classes should go in a separate module like

```
// my-helpers.js

export const countKeysInObject = (data) => {
  if (typeof data !== "object" || Array.isArray(data)) return 0;

  Object.keys(data).length;
}
```

some other file..

```
import { countKeysInObject } form 'my-helpers'
// And you can use it everywhere..
```

Comment: @FellowStranger, this was the recommendation I also made in [another answer to one of your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38883679/633183). webdeb + 1